# Stream remote framebuffer into NSView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I'm trying to implement a simple `VNC client` in Swift using `LibvnccClient`.

I have created a subclass of `NSView`. I create a `CGContext` and pass the data pointer to the library for use as the `framebuffer`. libvncclient updates the framebuffer as contents of the screen changes and calls my provided callback.

Here is the relevant code

```
class VNCClient {

    var localClient: rfbClient
    var view: NSView

    init(view: NSView) {
        guard let client_ptr = rfbGetClient(8, 3, 4) else {
            fatalError("Trouble")
        }

        self.view = view
        self.localClient = client_ptr.pointee

        localClient.MallocFrameBuffer = resize
        localClient.GotFrameBufferUpdate = update
        let fbPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(OpaquePointer((view as! RFBView).buffer))
        localClient.frameBuffer = fbPointer
        rfbClientSetClientData(&localClient, &viewTag, &self.view)
        var argc: Int32 = 0
        let b = rfbInitClient(&localClient, &argc, nil)
        if b == RFB_TRUE {
            print("Connected!")
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.001, repeats: true) {_ in
            if WaitForMessage(&self.localClient, 1) > 0 {
                HandleRFBServerMessage(&self.localClient)
            }
        }
    }

func update(client: UnsafeMutablePointer<rfbClient>?, x: Int32, y: Int32, w: Int32, h: Int32) -> Void {
    let cl = client!.pointee
    let view_ptr = rfbClientGetClientData(client, &viewTag)
    let view = view_ptr?.assumingMemoryBound(to: RFBView.self).pointee
    view?.setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: Int(x), y: Int(y), width: Int(w), height: Int(h)))
}


class RFBView: NSView {

    let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: 800, height: 600, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * 800, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)!

    var buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? {
        return ctx.data
    }
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        let image = ctx.makeImage()

        NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext.draw(image!, in: frame)

   }
```

It works but the display is not smooth. The server is running on the same machine in a VM so no network issues.

I'm redrawing the whole image for every update which I assume is the cause of the problem. So how can I redraw only the part of the framebuffer that is updated?

Is `CoreGraphics` fast enough for this or should I use `NSOpenGLView`?

Comment: no need to redraw it 1000 times per second. try 15fps `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1/15,` the lesser the better. It doesn't need to look like a movie

Comment: I did try playing with the frame rate, but I can't get acceptable performance out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that `HandleRFBServerMessage` would call `update` function once per iteration if there was an update. But that is not the case.

I replaced `update` with a stub that printed to console, and noticed it was being called more than thousand times when there was a lot of activity on the screen.

However, with the `setNeedsDisplay` call inside `update`, it was only being called a few hundred times. Since it was spending too much time rendering it was missing out on a few frames in between.

I moved the drawing code inside the `Timer` and it works perfectly now.

```
localClient.GotFrameBufferUpdate = { _, _, _, _, _ in needs_update = true }
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.016, repeats: true) {_ in
    if needs_update {
        view.display()
        needs_update = false
    }
    if WaitForMessage(&self.localClient, 1) > 0 {
        HandleRFBServerMessage(&self.localClient)
    }
}
```